# Writing and reading strings with Unsafe

Tags: java

I'm trying to write String into memory with sun.misc.Unsafe then i'm trying to read them back and i'm getting strange behaviour. I always get correctly just the last char of the string.

```
public String getId() {
    long idofset = objectOffset + this.id;
    int l = unsafe.getByte(idofset);
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    for (long i = idofset + 1 ; i < idofset + l + 1; i++) {
        temp.append(unsafe.getChar(i));
        System.out.println("reading:  " + unsafe.getChar(i)  + " at address: " + i);
    }
    return temp.toString();
}

@Override
public void setId(String id) {
    long idofset = objectOffset + this.id;
    int length = Math.min(id.length(), 14);
    unsafe.putByte(idofset, (byte)length );
    for (long i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println("writing:  " + id.charAt( (int)i)  + " at address: " + (idofset + i + 1));
        unsafe.putChar(idofset + i + 1 , id.charAt( (int)i ));
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
writing:  0 at address: 27297681
writing:  . at address: 27297682
writing:  0 at address: 27297683
writing:  4 at address: 27297684
writing:  6 at address: 27297685
writing:  6 at address: 27297686
writing:  5 at address: 27297687
writing:  7 at address: 27297688
writing:  0 at address: 27297689
writing:  0 at address: 27297690
writing:  1 at address: 27297691
writing:  4 at address: 27297692
writing:  8 at address: 27297693
writing:  9 at address: 27297694
0.04665700148936924
--------read-------------
reading:  ? at address: 27297681
reading:  ? at address: 27297682
reading:  ? at address: 27297683
reading:  ? at address: 27297684
reading:  ? at address: 27297685
reading:  ? at address: 27297686
reading:  ? at address: 27297687
reading:  ? at address: 27297688
reading:  ? at address: 27297689
reading:  ? at address: 27297690
reading:  ? at address: 27297691
reading:  ? at address: 27297692
reading:  ? at address: 27297693
reading:  9 at address: 27297694
?????????????9
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use sun.misc.Unsafe in the first place?  =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- `char` are two bytes in size so your address should be changing by two not one. Adding one at a time, means you are overwriting each char twice and only the last character is left uncorrupted.
- you can use Unsafe.copyMemory to copy the chars if you want low level ;)

If you want to see a library which makes extensive use of Unsafe try https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes  This has serialization uses a BytesMarshallable interface for data structures and access of text and binary using Unsafe to access off heap memory.  This includes writing and read `double` as text to native memory and parsing it.

Comment: What's difference between Java-Lang and off heap memory access provided in Chronicle-Core? I was looking for a library, where I can write objects off heap without worrying about writing size-of, serialization and deserialization methods?

Comment: @Abidi Java-Lang has been restructured and replaced by a few libraries, the most relevant for you is Chronicle-Bytes which supports BytesMarshallable for low level serialization of objects.  You might consider Marshallable in Chronicle-Wire which is more tollerant to schema changes but not as low level.

Comment: I was going through BytesMarshallable examples, for example MyByteable and MyScalars. In the examples, we create objects via new keyword, convert those objects in bytes and then dump them in off heap memory. Does it mean, we always need to create an object in heap first and then move it off heap?

Comment: @Abidi you need to have on heap fly weights which can be reused. In a single threaded process you might have as little as one object for each class.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example. Be sure to be as safe as you can with unsafe, because if you missed set faults from your C programming days, you can get them all back again with unsafe....

```
public static final Unsafe UNSAFE;
public static final long STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET;
public static final long STRING_OFFSET_FIELD_OFFSET;
public static final long STRING_COUNT_FIELD_OFFSET;
public static final boolean ENABLED;

private static final boolean WRITE_TO_FINAL_FIELDS = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("org.boon.write.to.final.string.fields", "true"));
private static final boolean DISABLE = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("org.boon.faststringutils", "false"));

private static Unsafe loadUnsafe() {
    try {
        Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

static {
    UNSAFE = DISABLE ? null : loadUnsafe();
    ENABLED = UNSAFE != null;
}

private static long getFieldOffset(String fieldName) {
    if (ENABLED) {
        try {
            return UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset(String.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // field undefined
        }
    }
    return -1L;
}

static {
    STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET = getFieldOffset("value");
    STRING_OFFSET_FIELD_OFFSET = getFieldOffset("offset");
    STRING_COUNT_FIELD_OFFSET = getFieldOffset("count");
}

private enum StringImplementation {
    DIRECT_CHARS {
        @Override
        public char[] toCharArray(String string) {
            return (char[]) UNSAFE.getObject(string, STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET);
        }

        @Override
        public String noCopyStringFromChars(char[] chars) {
            if (WRITE_TO_FINAL_FIELDS) {
                String string = new String();
                UNSAFE.putObject(string, STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET, chars);
                return string;
            } else {
                return new String(chars);
            }
        }
    },
    OFFSET {
        @Override
        public char[] toCharArray(String string) {
            char[] value = (char[]) UNSAFE.getObject(string, STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET);
            int offset = UNSAFE.getInt(string, STRING_OFFSET_FIELD_OFFSET);
            int count = UNSAFE.getInt(string, STRING_COUNT_FIELD_OFFSET);
            if (offset == 0 && count == value.length)
                // no need to copy
                return value;
            else
                return string.toCharArray();
        }

        @Override
        public String noCopyStringFromChars(char[] chars) {
            if (WRITE_TO_FINAL_FIELDS) {
                String string = new String();
                UNSAFE.putObject(string, STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET, chars);
                UNSAFE.putInt(string, STRING_COUNT_FIELD_OFFSET, chars.length);
                return string;
            } else {
                return new String(chars);
            }
        }
    },
    UNKNOWN {
        @Override
        public char[] toCharArray(String string) {
            return string.toCharArray();
        }

        @Override
        public String noCopyStringFromChars(char[] chars) {
            return new String(chars);
        }
    };

    public abstract char[] toCharArray(String string);
    public abstract String noCopyStringFromChars(char[] chars);
}

public static StringImplementation STRING_IMPLEMENTATION = computeStringImplementation();

private static StringImplementation computeStringImplementation() {

    if (STRING_VALUE_FIELD_OFFSET != -1L) {
        if (STRING_OFFSET_FIELD_OFFSET != -1L && STRING_COUNT_FIELD_OFFSET != -1L) {
            return StringImplementation.OFFSET;

        } else if (STRING_OFFSET_FIELD_OFFSET == -1L && STRING_COUNT_FIELD_OFFSET == -1L) {
            return StringImplementation.DIRECT_CHARS;
        } else {
            // WTF
            return StringImplementation.UNKNOWN;
        }
    } else {
        return StringImplementation.UNKNOWN;
    }
}

public static boolean hasUnsafe() {
    return ENABLED;
}

public static final char [] EMPTY_CHARS = new char[0];
public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

public static char[] toCharArray(final String string) {
    if (string == null) return EMPTY_CHARS;
    return STRING_IMPLEMENTATION.toCharArray(string);

}

public static char[] toCharArrayNoCheck(final CharSequence charSequence) {
    return toCharArray(charSequence.toString());
}

public static char[] toCharArray(final CharSequence charSequence) {
    if (charSequence == null) return EMPTY_CHARS;
    return toCharArray(charSequence.toString());
}

public static char[] toCharArrayFromBytes(final byte[] bytes, Charset charset) {
    return toCharArray(new String(bytes, charset != null ? charset : StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

public static String noCopyStringFromChars(final char[] chars) {
    if (chars==null) return EMPTY_STRING;
    return STRING_IMPLEMENTATION.noCopyStringFromChars(chars);
}


public static String noCopyStringFromCharsNoCheck(final char[] chars) {
    return STRING_IMPLEMENTATION.noCopyStringFromChars(chars);
}
```

The above is from Boon.

https://github.com/RichardHightower/boon